# Django- iterate a through a for loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following for loop in my django template displaying the items in my 'question' list.I want to print the value according to the index position of the list.However when I am trying to print it , nothing is showing in my browser. I have use a range function in my context and initialize it with a value of 2 in a key name 'n'.

This is my context

```
            context = {'range' : range(2),
                        'question': input_question,
                        'most_sim_Q': result[6],  
                        'question_scores': question_scores}
            return render(request, 'predict/result.html', context)
```

this is the template

```
{% extends 'predict/base.html'%}
{% block content %}
    {% for text in range %}
    <!--parsing the input question-->
    <h2>Input Question: </h2><br>
        {{question.text}}
    <!--Parsing the most similar question-->
    <h2>most similar question's are: </h2><br>
        {{most_sim_Q.n.most_sim_Q}}
    <!--parsing the top 10 most smilialr question-->    
        <h2> Top 10 most similar questions found are : </h2><br>
            {%for ques_key, values in question_scores.items%}
                {% for que, score in question_score.i.items %}
                    <h3> {{ que }} ==>  {{score}} </h3>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
    <h3>--------------------------------------------------</h3>        
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I am printing question.text where question is the list containing two values but {{question.text}}.This is my output

```
Input Question:

most similar question's are:

Top 10 most similar questions found are :

--------------------------------------------------
Input Question:

most similar question's are:

Top 10 most similar questions found are :

--------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not working, because Jinja2 syntax is different than what you're writing. You could try this instead:

```
{% for text in range(2) %}
    {{ question[text] }}
{% endfor %}
```

It uses a range function that's provided in jinja2 instead of using a range from the python server

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError at /

Could not parse the remainder: '[text]' from 'question[text]'   .......
it is showing this error

Comment: Do you need to specify the range in python? There is also a function called range in jinja2, you could use that instead, I edited my answer to show you how that works